# Text field with brakets and underline

Tags: html, input, textfield

how to make input field like bellow link for enter phone number.

http://phoenix-tape.com/?p=7

this underline need to disappear when enter the numbers.

any one can help me ?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this jquery plugin would be a solution for you

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: you are welcome, please let me ask you why did you mark the other as the correct answer?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake. do you know how to make that mask show when page load. now its only show when i click inside the field

Comment: I think you can't. There is no docs for it, just some instructions and demo. But maybe if you read the uncompressed version you might find a way. Ahother way would be to focus on the input field when page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function which is called when the user clicks the input box to clear the field.
Example:

```
<script>
clear(){
document.querySelector('input#tel').value="";
}
</script>

<input id="tel" on click="clear();"/>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: thanks for reply dude. Ateszki give me exact what i need. thanks